# Sublime Cursor History

Tags: sublimetext3

I know Sublime Text offers a feature to jump back and forth.

But, when I browse through my source code using "Go To Definition" a couple of times, and use "Jump back" to jump back to where I started it won't take me there. It works for a couple of previous cursor positions but not all the way through.

Is it because there is a limit as to how many cursor locations it can hold, or does it have like a timer to flush the data?

How can I make it work, so I can jump back to as many positions as I want?

Build-3176